# Joining a Dictionary with a MySQL Table

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have a dictionary of key-value pairs, e.g. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`, and a MySQL Table, e.g.

```
key value extra
a   1     ...
b   2     ...
c   3     ...
```

What I would like to do is `SELECT` all the rows whose key and value are in my dictionary (for their extra data, obviously). Since the dictionary is created dynamically, and can be large (100s of key-values), I was wondering what is the best way to do this.

Two options that come to mind are,

1. Generate the SQL query dynamically, e.g.

   ```
   query = []
   param = []
   for i in d.items():
       query.append('(key = ? AND value = ?)')
       param.extend(i)
   execute('SELECT * FROM t WHERE ' + ' OR '.join(query), param)
   ```

   The drawback: I don't like dynamic code generation. It's harder to debug, maintain and extend, it's more prone to vulnerabilities, etc.
2. Create a temporary table, e.g.

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (key VARCHAR(255), value VARCHAR(1023));
   ```

   Populate it, e.g.

   ```
   stmt = compile('INSERT INTO tmp (key, value) VALUES (?, ?)')
   stmt.execute_many(d.items())
   ```

   And then use a join, e.g.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM t JOIN tmp ON (t.key = tmp.key AND t.value = tmp.value)
   ```

   The drawback: I'm not sure, but creating a temporary table and issuing batch inserts only to perform a single join seems less efficient that issuing a single query.

My question is, are there any other options? and which option is the best?

Thanks.

Comment: Option 1: `sql = 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE '+' OR '.join('(key={} AND value={})'.format(k, v) for k,v in d.iteritems()) if d else None`, but like you said, it's much harder to maintain

Comment: I would go with temporary table, as I feel you'd hit some obscure limit on query size or number of subclauses in `OR` if the dictionary is very large. As for performance, the only answer is profiling for your specific usecase.